# HTML5 Video Has Dark Gradient on the Bottom that doesn't fit the container

Tags: html, css, video, cloudinary

I have a `<video>` tag in my HTML, that looks like this:

```html
<video control>
    <source src="[video_url].webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="[video_url].mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p>Your browser does not support this type of video</p>
</video>
```

This video is hosted on Cloudinary, and I'm doing an inline transform with the `src` to get a specific dimension (`w_450,h_350`).

[image: Video at full size]

The video by itself looks fine, however I have a media query where I shrink the video by 100px in both width and height to fit smaller screen sizes

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    video { width: 350px; height: 250px }
}
```

[image: Video after media query]

And as you can see, the video container has a shadow that overflows past the width and height of the new container size. If I click play on the video, the box shadow persists.

How do I make the box-shadow for the controls fit the actual size of the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than applying height width to the  tag you should enclose it within a

```
   <div>
       <video control>
           <source src="[video_url].webm" type="video/webm">
           <source src="[video_url].mp4" type="video/mp4">
           <p>Your browser does not support this type of video</p>
       </video>
   </div>
```

And then apply your css to the

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) 
   {
       div{ width: 350px; height: 250px }
       video{ width: 100%; height: 100% }
   }
```